# GDPR data flow mapping and inventory

Tags: compliance, gdpr

Anybody can share some tips on how to create a nice GDPR data flow mapping and inventory?

Any sample diagrams? What diagrams types are best to be used here?

Would you show high level diagram and sub-diagrams for each component set?

How would you approach it for a bigger system (monolith with dozen of micro-services, several data sources etc)?

Don't want to re-invent diagram type, make something non standard, hence my question for experienced GDPR folks that did this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Data Flow Diagram will help map out all the locations data is stored, processed and in transit.

This gives a great high level overview of the data.

Some good sources can be found here:

- https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/data-flow-diagram/what-is-data-flow-diagram/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450498/what-are-the-data-flow-diagrams-dfd